# Why Python exit when I make Http request?

Tags: python, http, request

I'm working with Windows :

```
import os
import http.client as h

co = h.HTTPSConnection("www.google.com")
co.request("GET","/")
res = co.getresponse()
print(res.status,res.reason)
os.system("pause")
```

When I open the command line, all work perfectly : "200 OK"

But when I copy this in a file and save it, I have an error and the programm stop. 
I found a "solution", when I run my app, the folder "__pycache__" containing "http.cpython-34" is created. 
And I have to open the "http.cpython-34" file to see "200 OK"
Is there another way to run correctly my programm without opening the "http.cpython-34" file ?

EDIT : I found the solution. My file was called http.py. But when I rename it, it work perfectly :)

Comment: what is pause supposed to do? I also get a 302 not 200

Comment: Uh, python programs naturally end when you get to the end of the file? I'm not quite sure what you're expecting. (Also, I do get `200 OK` on linux, using python 3.4)

Comment: I use os.system("pause") because without this instruction my programm close immediatly

Answer (score -1):

I don't think `os.system("pause")` is what you want to use here. That will try to launch a subprocess with the command `pause`, which will not actually pause the running Python program. Generally if you want to pause and wait for a keypress or something you can use `raw_input()` to pause and wait for user input in Python 2.7 or `input()` in Python 3.